# Can sound waves be cancelled out with a perfect mirror?

Tags: waves, acoustics

Can sound waves be cancelled out with a perfect mirror? Can this be applied to active noise cancelling headphones to make it perfect?

Comment: What does _perfect mirror_ mean in this context?

Comment: @nicoguaro I think what the OP means is if the sound wave bounces back from a surface perfectly, shifting it's phase by 180 deg and superposition would then give zero.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, it would work for waves that impinge perpendicularly to the surface but that's it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can.... at only a finite set of frequencies ($\omega=ck$) such that the two paths to the microphone (or ear) are 180 degrees ($\pi$ radians) out of phase.

If the path length difference (plus the $\pi$ upon reflection) add to $\pi$ (modulo $2\pi$):

$$k\Delta L + \pi = \pi\,\ {\rm mod}  \, 2\pi$$

or

$$ k = \frac{2\pi n}{\Delta L}\ \ \ \ n\in(0,1,2,\cdots) $$

where $k=\lambda/2\pi$ is the wave number.

Hence:

$$ \lambda = \frac{\Delta L}n $$

Now if

$$ \lambda = \frac{\Delta L}{n+\frac 1 2} $$

the amplitude should be doubled.

(Note: I assumed "perfect mirror" means the reflected amplitude exactly equals the input amplitude...but is that even possible?  A parabolic mirror will amplify the reflect sound, a flat mirror could disperse it. There is a lot to consider.)